# Extract rows of characters with different length from a large list into a dataframe?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, character, subset

I uploaded a .txt file with `"|,"` separators, so I used `strsplit()`

```
lob<-readLines("lob_lobbying.txt")
lob<-strsplit(lob, "|,", fixed=TRUE)
```

However, the output is a large list, with length 1213906. Each of these are a list of type characters, but some of them have length 16 and other 17.

I want to extract each of these rows and bind them into a data frame.

For example when i do

```
X <-rbind(lob[[1]],lob[[2]], lob[[3]])
df<-as.data.frame(X)
```

The X is exactly the type of output i want (because i then can do data.frame and it works perfect!) However, given the length of the list is 1213906 i need to automate this process.

But as soon as i try to `do.call(rbind, lob)` it does not work. I get

> "number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 5)"

I think is because some of these character strings have length 16 and others length 17.

Is there a loop to extract each of this strings based if they have 16 or 17 characters and then bind them?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. Right now it's hard to do more than guess as to what your data looks like and how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, .., we can use `do.call` after padding `NA` at the end when the `length` of the `list` element is less than the `max`imum `length`

```
lob <- lapply(lob, `length<-`, max(lengths(lob)))
df1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lob)
```

---

Also, instead of using `readLines` and then splitting with `strsplit`, this can be read with `read.table` with the `sep` argument and `fill = TRUE`

```
df1 <- read.table("lob_lobbying.txt", sep="|", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: So df1 <- read.table("lob_lobbying.txt", sep="|", fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) does not work because the number of observations are reduced significantly. The warning message EOF within quoted string comes and i think its because R is not recognizing the | properly....

Comment: @MariaD.Perez  The EOF is a different issue.